# How do I import Firebase Auth from the reserved URL without it fetching a second copy of firebase-app.js from gstatic.com?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## tl;dr

I am importing the following files:

- `/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-app.js`
- `/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-auth.js`

`firebase-auth.js` in turn imports the following file:

- `https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.3/firebase-app.js`

I think this the reason why `getFirestore(app)` is throwing an error with message `Error: Service firestore is not available`.[1]

**Is there any way to import files from `/__/firebase/x.y.z/*` such that transitive imports are also scoped to `/__/firebase/x.y.z/` rather than `gstatic.com`?**

## Preconditions

I created a simple Firebase web project where I use Firestore and Firebase Hosting. Here are the relevant excerpts from each file I'm hosting.

I edit these files directly in /public and don't use a module bundler or any other build step.

index.html

```
<script type=module src=firebasemap.js></script>
```

firebasemap.js

```
import { initializeApp } from '/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-app.js'

import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged /* and others */ } from '/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-auth.js'
import { getDoc, getFirestore /* and others */ } from '/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-firestore.js'
```

```
  const response = await fetch('/__/firebase/init.json')
  const config = await response.json()
  app = initializeApp(config)
  db = getFirestore(app)
  auth = getAuth(app)
```

## Expected behaviour

The call to `getFirestore(app)` returns an instance of the FirestoreClient.

## Actual behaviour

The call to `getFirestore(app)` throws an error with message `Error: Service firestore is not available`

## Observations

I've read that this error can be thrown when the Firebase libraries aren't loaded correctly, especially when the main Firebase library is loaded more than once.[1]

By examining the network tab in the web inspector, I see that I'm correctly importing `firebase-app.js` and `firestore-auth.js` from `/__/firebase/9.8.3`, but that I'm importing a second copy of `firebase-app.js` from `gstatic.com`.

By downloading a copy of `/__/firebase/9.8.3/firebase-auth.js`, I can see that the import at the start of the file is hardcoded to `gstatic.com`, resulting in the duplicate copy of `firebase-app.js` being imported.

## Question

- Is this double import the reason why I receive the `Error: Service firestore is not available` error message?

  - If so, how do I fix it? Is there a way to import the Firebase libraries from the reserved URL without them importing a second copy from gstatic.com?
  - If not, how do I get access to the copy of the Firebase App object on which these services are initialized? Do I need to import a copy of `firebase-app.js` in my own script?

1: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6055#issuecomment-1062307359

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to import libraries for Firebase 9, and even though those library source files were available in `/__/firebase/9.y.z`, importing them from those URLs apparently aren't supported. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#libraries_hosting-urls.